# asterisk reboot via crono

Tags: asterisk, voip

we have a Zycoo Voip system. We cannot understand why but the system lost its connection and need frequently to be booted/restarted.
We do not know how to debug it. To be more specific, we have set a crono to reboot and reload sip parameters on scheduled basis. This is our crono

```
    # file is /etc/crontabs/root
    50 3 * * *  /bin/rm -f /dead.letter
    0 */2 * * * sh /etc/scripts/logger.sh
    */5 * * * * sh /etc/scripts/emailtofax.sh
    */30 * * * * sh /etc/scripts/checkfree.sh
    0 0 * * * asterisk -rx "database deltree DCID"
    50 * * * * asterisk -rx "sip reload"
    0 8 * * * asterisk /bin/reboot
```

**It looks like is not executing it at all.**

**We are running Asterisk 1.8.7.1**

What is wrong with the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work
0 8 * * * /bin/reboot

Answer (score 1):

There are no /bin/reboot command in asterisk

Use

```
 0 8 * * *  /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "core restart now"
```